# Garbled UTF-8 characters in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

```
<?php
        require ('sql_connect.php');

        $query = "select * from `products`";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $imagem = $row['imagem'];
            $texto = $row['texto'];

            echo "<img src=Images/Products/$imagem> <br> $texto";
        }
        ?>
```

I have the image and the text of the image that i want to show in my database.

I show the image but i have problems with the text... The text dont show the enters/spaces and the accents.

Image of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khw12.png

I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khw12.png#1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should use **[`MySQLi`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[`PDO`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** instead of **[`mysql_*`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php)** functions, which are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. [More information avalible here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you didn't properly set the encoding to `UTF-8` *(or another one that contains all characters you want to display)*. To do this, you need to:

- **Set the encoding** to `UTF-8` **in the database** itself (you can skip this step if you can see the text properly in PhpMyAdmin).
- **Tell PHP that you're using `UTF-8`**. To do this, run:

  ```
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  ```

  right after you connect to the database *(add this line to the end of your `sql_connect.php` file)*.

---

Please note that you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions anymore *(see my comment on your question)*. If you switch to MySQLi, you can run this:

```
$db->set_charset("utf-8");
```

to change the charset.

---

See also:

- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/1935077)
- [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1935077)