# Insert Enters/Spaces of Text in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php

```
<?php
        require ('sql_connect.php');

        $query = "select * from `products`";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $imagem = $row['imagem'];
            $texto = $row['texto'];

            echo "<img src=Images/Products/$imagem> <br> $texto";
        }
        ?>
```

I have the image and the text of the image that i want to show in my database.

I show the image but i have problems with the text... The text dont show the ENTERS/SPACES. There are some ways to resolve this?

Image of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51Pp.png

I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51Pp.png#1

Database: utf8_general_ci

In database text is saving with enters/spaces...

Comment: check what it is saving in DB for the field `texto`. Is it saving with spaces/enters/accented character?

Comment: Its saving with enters/spaces...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbled UTF-8 characters in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042950/garbled-utf-8-characters-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve Line Breaks From TextArea When Writing To MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048849/preserve-line-breaks-from-textarea-when-writing-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something is wrong on the encoding of connection. in that `sql_connect.php` file, after you connect, please execute this one:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

if this doesn't help, try this one:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

where `$conn` is your connection. This will make sure everything is `UTF-8`

Also please **make sure** the column on your tables are `utf8_general_ci`

After all this, please re-enter your data to your db and try again.